# Single Task Updating Multiple Progress Bars

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

**I would like to update multiple JavaFX progress bars via a single task.** The progress bars are created in another controller so I put the progress bars in a hashmap to access them through a public method.  I am choosing a single task instead of one task per progress bar to decrease the number of web service calls since each call will be bringing me all the needed information for all of the progress bars.  I was previously binding the progress property to a tasks progress property and that worked great.  **Again, changing to a single task to reduce web service calls made me curious as to the best way to go about updating multiple progress bars via a single task.**

The following did not update the progress bars.  I even attempted to do the following wrapped in a Platform.runLater with no success.

```
// JOB PROGRESS CONTROLLER:

private HashMap<String,ProgressBar> jobProgressMap;

public void updateProgress(String aJobName, double aPercent)
{
    jobProgressMap.get(aJobName).setProgress(aPercent);
}

//TASK IN A COMPLETELY DIFFERENT PARENT CONTROLLER

public Task updateProgressBarTask() 
{
    return new Task() 
    {
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception 
        {
            while (this.isCancelled() != true)
            { 
                //Web Service call here
                for each jobName/progress unit
                {
                        //platform run later                            
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            @Override public void run() 
                            {
                       jobProgressController.updateProgress(jobName, percent);
                            }
              ...
```

EDIT:  I've moved that code back into the controller where it was creating the progress bars and it worked.  However  I still would like to see an answer of the most efficient way to update multiple progress bars from a task in a different controller than where the progress bars are instantiated.

Comment: You cannot update the progress bars in a background thread. Please show the version where you tried to do this with a `Platform.runLater(...)`

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted, so if it's not working your errors are likely in other parts of your code. (I could make a few guesses but they would be just that: guesses.) Create and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.